# Using xsl and href

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have this xml file

```
<myxml>
  <section name="AAA">
    <Title>TEST</Title>
    <Log>\\PC\log.log</Log>
    <Data>1267</Data>
  </section>
</myxml>
```

Now I'm trying to use xsl file so I will have a reference with the Title
as the text displayed and Log as the link.
I tried using these but can't make this work together

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="myxml/AAA/Title"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <a href="{Log}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```